# Different Devise configurations for each model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two models which are using Devise for authentication: `User` and `Uploader` with strictly separated pages and views (the former has access to the app, the latter just to one upload view).

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models) and everything is working well, but now I'm looking for ways to have a different Devise config for each model.

For example: `config.authentication_keys = [:email]` for `User` and `config.authentication_keys = [:username]` for `Uploader`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard Devise config file to set a sensible set of defaults for all configuration options.

Then for the special cases you want to override in the other model, you can just set them in the model itself:

```
class Uploader < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :etc

  # Override authentication_keys for Uploader
  self.authentication_keys = [:username]
end
```

Should do the trick.